# integral $\int \frac{2x}{(3x-2)^2+2^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{2x}{(3x-2)^2+2^2}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

$\int \frac{1}{(3x-2)^2+2^2}\, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(\frac{3x-2}{2})+C$

But what can I do with the $2x$ in the numerator?

Comment: Well, it means that you'll have to use a different method. Partial fraction decomposition might be helpful here.

Comment: It is almost the derivative of the denominator.

Comment: @Ispil how can I use Partial fraction if the denominator is not a sum?

Comment: Right, right. It also seems that I was mistaken with the factoring out of x. Apologies.

Comment: @Bernard so I will get $\int \frac{18x-12}{(3x-2)^2+2^2}+\int  \frac{-16x+12}{(3x-2)^2+2^2}=ln(\frac{1}{2} arctan(\frac{3x-2}{2})+\int  \frac{-16x+12}{(3x-2)^2+2^2}$

Answer (score 1):

This can be written as:
$$\frac{1}{9} \int \frac{(18x-12+12)dx}{9x^2-12x+8}=$$
$$\frac{1}{9} \int \frac{(18x-12)dx}{9x^2-12x+8}+\frac{4}{3} \int \frac{dx}{(3x-2)^2+2^2}=$$
$$\frac{1}{9} \ln(9x^2-12x+8)+\frac{2}{9}\tan^{-1}{\frac{3x-2}{2}}+C$$

Comment: it is $\frac{1}{9}ln(\frac{1}{2}arctan(\frac{3x-2}{2}))+\frac{4}{3}(\frac{1}{2}arctan(\frac{3x-2}{2})$

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get two arc tangents??